# Musical symbols from Lilyglyphs in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, music

What do I need to work with tikz and lilyglyphs (and spanish babel)? Lilyglyphs doesn't work for me in this example. I use LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017 / Debian)

Another problem in this code is that sharps and flats are lost when `\pgfmathprintnumber` is removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

%\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%<-- Want to use this

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
{\huge Círculo de Quintas}
\break

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw node {\pgfmathprintnumber{0}}; % <-- Want to remove this
    \foreach \x/\xmaj/\xmin in {1/C/A,2/G/E,3/D/B,
            4/A/F\sharp,5/E/C\sharp,6/B/G\sharp,
            7/{G\flat/F\sharp}/{E\flat/D\sharp},8/D\flat/B\flat,9/A\flat/F,
            10/E\flat/C,11/B\flat/G,12/F/D}
        {
        \draw (-30*\x+120:3.8)  node {\textbf{\xmaj M}};
        \draw (-30*\x+120:2.8)  node {\textbf{\xmin m}};
        }
  \draw [decorate,
         decoration={text along path,
         text={Tonalidades con sostenidos ->},
         text align=left}]
         (60:5)  arc [start angle =60, end angle=-10,radius=5];
  \draw [decorate,
         decoration={text along path,
         text={<- Tonalidades con bemoles},
         text align=right}]
         (180:5)  arc [start angle =180, end angle=120,radius=5];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: circulo de quintas]

Comment: In my example code, when i remove the `\pgfmathprintnumber`instruction, the sharps and flats disappear.

Answer (score 1):

This is at best a workaround, which I will be happy to remove, but perhaps this is somewhat useful. It stores the symbols in `\saveboxes`, which get reused.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%<-- Want to use this
\newsavebox\SharpBox
\sbox\SharpBox{\sharp[scale=1]}
\newcommand\Sharp{\usebox\SharpBox}
\newsavebox\FlatBox
\sbox\FlatBox{\flat[scale=1]}
\newcommand\Flat{\usebox\FlatBox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}


\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{center}
{\huge C\'irculo de Quintas}
\break

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %\draw node {\pgfmathprintnumber{0}}; % <-- Want to remove this
    \foreach \x/\xmaj/\xmin in {1/C/A,2/G/E,3/D/B,
            4/A/F\Sharp,5/E/C\Sharp,6/B/G\Sharp,
            7/{G\Flat/F\Sharp}/{E\Flat/D\Sharp},8/D\Flat/B\Flat,9/A\Flat/F,
            10/E\Flat/C,11/B\Flat/G,12/F/D}
        {
        \draw (-30*\x+120:3.8)  node[font=\bfseries] {\xmaj M};
        \draw (-30*\x+120:2.8)  node[font=\bfseries] {\xmin m};
        }
  \draw [decorate,
         decoration={text along path,
         text={Tonalidades con sostenidos ->},
         text align=left}]
         (60:5)  arc [start angle =60, end angle=-10,radius=5];
  \draw [decorate,
         decoration={text along path,
         text={<- Tonalidades con bemoles},
         text align=right}]
         (180:5)  arc [start angle =180, end angle=120,radius=5];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```